# My application show different versions on different devices

Tags: android, manifest

I have a strange problem. My application showing on some devices version code and some other devices it's showing version name for single application under `Settings>Applications>Manage Applications>app name`.

My manifest.xml file is as:

```
  android:versionCode="2"
  android:versionName="2.0.21"
```

I want to show same version name for all the devices/users. Could any one help me on it?

Answer (score 1):

Some manufacturers or ROM builders can display either the version code, or version name (or both). Just put the same value in both fields. You will lose the ability to put a string value for the versionName.

Example:

```
 android:versionCode="2"
 android:versionName="2"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just how it works. Earlier versions of Android display the version code whilst later versions display the version name (In the Manage Applications screen).

As a rule, you should use the version code internally and the version name for anything that the user can see.

Comment: So, how could I hide version code from manage application screen? because I must have to use version name in application.